# How to use `new google.maps.Marker()` with `vue2-google-maps`

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, vuejs2, vue2-google-maps

For some reasons, I have to use `new google.maps.Marker()` with [`vue2-google-maps`](https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps), but I don't know how to start since the documents and many people use `<GmapMarker ... />` in the HTML part instead.

I've tried to search but the document doesn't cover this.

Right now my code looks like this, it doesn't have any error but it doesn't work either (the map is present but the marker isn't shown):

```html
<template>
  <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    <GmapMap
      :center="{ lat: 0, lng: 0 }"
      ref="mapRef"
    >
    </GmapMap>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps';

export default {
  computed: {
    google: VueGoogleMaps.gmapApi,
  },
  methods: {
    init() {
      new this.google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
          lat: 0,
          lng: 0
        },
        map: this.$refs.mapRef,
      });
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    this.init()
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out. Here's what I did:

---

**Create a map variable in `data()`**

```
data() {
  return {
    map: undefined,
  }
},
```

**Set it using this function in `mounted()`**

```
mounted() {
  this.$refs.mapRef.$mapPromise.then((map) => {
    this.map = map;
    this.init();
  });
},
```

**Now, Bob's your uncle, you can use `this.map` where ever you want**

```
methods: {
  init() {
    new this.google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: 0,
        lng: 0
      },
      map: this.map,
    });
  },
}
```